# FSharp.Core.dll is missing in reference assemblies

Tags: f#, visual-studio-2022

I have a F# project in VS2019 . By default, when I open the application, the FSharp.Core.dll is referring to C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\FSharp\2.0\Runtime\v4.0\FSharp.Core.dll.

when I open the same project in 2022VS, the FSharp.Core.dll is not getting referenced.

I have also installed the F# related individual components also [workloads image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pn4J8.png)

```
I found the FSharp.Core.dll in various locations in VS2022 as below:
1.C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\FSharpSdk\.NETFramework\v4.0\4.3.0.0
2.C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\FSharp\FSharp.Core.dll

However, this location 3. C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\FSharp\2.0\Runtime\v4.0\FSharp.Core.dll. is empty.(which is getting referred in 2019 VS)
```

I have tried to install from nuget packages,but still there is no location 3.
can I refer the dll's present in location 1 and location 2 .
what is the difference between all those 3 locations.
which dll should I be referring.

can anyone help me in understanding this..

Thanks in advance !!

Comment: .NET Framework or .NET Core? What version?